# SharePoint Workflow Performance considerations

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

This is not regarding a specific problem, but rather the most common ways people badly design workflows which impacts performance. I have the task of improving the performance of some workflows in O365 hosted SharePoint, where they are complaining that the workflow can take up to 30 minutes to complete. Obviously this isn't normal, and I need to work out why this is happening (most likely when many list items have the workflow running).

There is a lot of item updates occurring which could be a source of delay in the workflow, and also many steps are running in serial which, with some tweaking, could be made to run in parallel. Is reducing item updates and running simple calculations in parallel going to improve performance considerably or would I be barking up the wrong tree? **What is the primary factor in workflow speed?**

Extra information about the workflow: It is a 2013 workflow running on a regular list, but it makes many changes to the item at different stages. It also has different behaviour depending on the content type.

Comment: Check this https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/3076399/sharepoint-2013-workflow-throttling-and-performance-in-sharepoint-online-and-project-online

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it, but I don't believe it is being throttled.

Comment: Check this thread https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/SharePoint-Online-Workflow-permformance/td-p/46390

Comment: Thanks. I've had a look at that and it seems like they've offered a solution for speeding up slow parts of a workflow, but not saying much about how to find which parts are running slowly.